# When to use `std::hypot(x,y)` over `std::sqrt(x*x + y*y)`

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-accuracy

The [documentation of `std::hypot`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) says that:

> Computes the square root of the sum of the squares of x and y, without undue overflow or underflow at intermediate stages of the computation.

I struggle to conceive a test case where `std::hypot` should be used over the trivial `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`.

The following test shows that `std::hypot` is roughly 20x slower than the naive calculation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::mt19937_64 mt;
    const auto samples = 10000000;
    std::vector<double> values(2 * samples);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> urd(-100.0, 100.0);
    std::generate_n(values.begin(), 2 * samples, [&]() {return urd(mt); });
    std::cout.precision(15);

    {
        double sum = 0;
        auto s = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (auto i = 0; i < 2 * samples; i += 2) {
            sum += std::hypot(values[i], values[i + 1]);
        }
        auto e = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::fixed <<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(e - s).count() << "us --- s:" << sum << std::endl;
    }
    {
        double sum = 0;
        auto s = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (auto i = 0; i < 2 * samples; i += 2) {
            sum += std::sqrt(values[i]* values[i] + values[i + 1]* values[i + 1]);
        }
        auto e = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(e - s).count() << "us --- s:" << sum << std::endl;
    }
}
```

So I'm asking for guidance, when must I use `std::hypot(x,y)` to obtain correct results over the much faster `std::sqrt(x*x + y*y)`.

**Clarification:** I'm looking for answers that apply when `x` and `y` are floating point numbers. I.e. compare:

```
double h = std::hypot(static_cast<double>(x),static_cast<double>(y));
```

to:

```
double xx = static_cast<double>(x);
double yy = static_cast<double>(y);
double h = std::sqrt(xx*xx + yy*yy);
```

Comment: I think you should also compare it with `std::abs(std::complex<double>(x,y))` as in [std::hypot](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) page

Comment: Late, but the cppreference documentation also says as a note (so no guarantee by the standard) that "Implementations usually guarantee precision of less than 1 ulp (units in the last place)." `x*x + y*y` can lose a couple of bits of precision, if with round to nearest set. This means that `std::sqrt(x*x+y*y)` can be off by a bit or two. A better algorithm than `std::sqrt(x*x+y*y)` is needed to get that guarantee. (continued)

Comment: To make matters worse, suppose you've mucked with the rounding? That will definitely get in the way of achieving that sub-ulp precision. `hypot` has to set the rounding so as to attain that accuracy and then restore the rounding back to your settings. This setting and resetting of rounding behavior is what makes `std:hypot(x,y)` considerably slower than `std::sqrt(x*x+y*y)`.

Comment: I enjoyed this question, but I still wanted to know why the performance disparity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764978/why-hypot-function-is-so-slow has a discussion of this. Specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3764993/725805 explains It for me.

Comment: The sqrt function has the property that any relative error present in the input is halved in the result of the square root  --- i.e. sqrt(x*(1+e)) ~=~ sqrt(x)*(1+e/2) ---   (whereas squaring doubles it), so the square root method is not as bad it as would seem from the above. The extra runtime for hypot is partly made of up choosing among different methods to get extra precision, and steps to avoid over/underflow, but also special tests for inf  (e.g. hypot(inf,NaN) -> inf, whereas the other approach gives you NaN).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation you quoted

> Computes the square root of the sum of the squares of x and y, **without undue overflow or underflow at intermediate stages of the computation**.

If `x*x + y*y` overflows, then if you carry out the calculation manually, you'll get the wrong answer. If you use `std::hypot`, however, it guarantees that the intermediate calculations will not overflow.

You can see an example of this disparity [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c36801163209d24).

If you are working with numbers which you know will not overflow the relevant representation for your platform, you can happily use the naive version.

Comment: `std::hypot`'s parameters are floating-pont types, so if you use int here it'll also be promoted to floating-point.

Comment: I might not have been 100% clear in my question. I'm only interested in difference between the two when  `double` precision arguments are used.  Because integer overflow is handled by the type promotion, not the `hypot` function. But something in `hypot` makes it 20x slower than the naive implementation (even with type promotion). Why is this and when will it save my tushie?

Comment: As can be seen [in the example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d957adbf7ab753a0) there is no disparity when using double precision arguments. Specifically I'm looking for `double x,y` where a disparity will appear.

Comment: @EmilyL. just make the value [large enough](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af4dd4c58f4f7070).

Comment: @TartanLlama [I still don't see a difference](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd6452c0a362b4c8).

Comment: @TartanLlama Now we're getting somewhere :) So when the intermediary result exceeds `1.7e308` then there will be a difference. If you edit your answer to include this and skip the integer overflow discussion. I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @EmilyL. for a given platform, sure. More generally, when it exceeds `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`.