# Why is sqrt(x*x + y*y) != math.hypot(x, y) in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, math, floating-point, python-3.8

I'm trying to run some tests on the shiny new Python 3.8 and noticed an issue with [`math.hypot`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.hypot). From the docs:

> For a two dimensional point `(x, y)`, this is equivalent to computing
>   the hypotenuse of a right triangle using the Pythagorean theorem,
>   `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`.

However, these are not equivalent in 3.8:

```
>>> from math import hypot, sqrt
>>> x, y = 95, 168
>>> sqrt(x*x + y*y), hypot(x, y), sqrt(x*x + y*y) == hypot(x, y)
(193.0, 193.00000000000003, False)
>>> sqrt(x*x + y*y).is_integer(), hypot(x, y).is_integer()
(True, False)
```

In 3.7 both ways produce exactly the same result (`"193.0"`, which is considered an integer).

Comment: From a pure math standpoint they are the same, but the interpreter will call them different based on the precision of the method.

Comment: I don't think this is a good duplicate to redirect to. There is a lot of specific information regarding `hypot` that can be provided here, whereas most of the explanations in the so-called duplicate do not apply to this question.

Comment: @PascalCuoq there's one for C++: [When to use `std::hypot(x,y)` over `std::sqrt(x*x + y*y)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32435796/995714)

Comment: To the question of what changed in Python 3.8, the answer is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/8474  `hypot` went from accepting 2 arguments to accepting an arbitrary number of arguments, and in the process the 2-argument version changed from a straight C libm call to something more complicated - the two-argument special case of the general machinery. Possibly this should be considered a bug, and 2-argument hypot should be special-cased to use the libm-provided hypot.

Comment: @MarkDickinson On the other hand, there is no guarantee about what the libm-provided `hypot` is, so the new version is more platform-independent at least.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function `hypot` offers **another** approximation of the mathematical expression √(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>), just like the floating-point expression `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` is an approximation of this same mathematical expression.

The function `hypot` is recommended because it solves very noticeable defects that are present in the floating-point computation `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` with very large or small values. For instance, if `x` is only a bit larger than the square root of the maximum finite floating-point value, `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` always produces `+inf` because `x*x` produces `+inf`.

Compare:

```
>>> x, y = 95E200, 168E200
>>> sqrt(x*x + y*y), hypot(x, y)
(inf, 1.93e+202)
>>> z, t = 95E-200, 168E-200
>>> sqrt(z*z + t*t), hypot(z, t)
(0.0, 1.93e-198)
```

For these two (respectively very large and very small) pairs of inputs, `hypot` is doing fine, whereas `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` is catastrophically wrong.

---

When the naïve version `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` works reasonably well (when the values `x` and `y` are neither very large nor very small), it can be may be more or less accurate than the function `hypot` depending on the values of `x` and `y`. They can both be expected to produce a result that is a few ULPs away from the mathematical result. But since they are different approximations obtained by different methods, they may differ (in the worst case by twice “a few ULPs”).

One typical implementation for `hypot(x, y)` is first to swap `x` and `y` if necessary so that `x` has the largest magnitude, and then compute `x * sqrt(1 + (y/x)*(y/x))`. This solves the problem with `x*x` overflowing. As a side-effect, it means that **even when there is no overflow**, the result is slightly different from `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`.

Note that it's normal that `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` is more precise when you apply it to small integers (as you do in your test): when `x` and `y` are small integers, `x*x` and `y*y` and their sum can be computed exactly as floating-point values. If this sum is the square of an integer, the floating-point function `sqrt` can only compute this integer. In short, in this scenario the computations, despite being floating-point, are exact from beginning to end. In contrast, the typical `hypot` implementation above starts by computing `x/y` (in your test, `95.0/168.0`), and this result is not in general representable exactly as a floating-point value. The first step already incurs an approximation, and this approximation can result in the final result being wrong (as it is in your test)!

---

There is no standard algorithm for `hypot`: it is only expected to compute a good approximation of the mathematical expression √(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>) while avoiding the overflow and underflow problems. [This article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.09481.pdf) shows different implementations, and points out that the popular implementation that I mentioned sacrifices accuracy to avoid overflow and underflow (but the article also provides a floating-point implementation for `hypot` that is **more accurate** than `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` even where `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` works).