# Accurate sqrt(1 + (x/2)^2) + x/2

Tags: floating-point, language-agnostic, numeric, numerical-computing

I need to compute `sqrt(1 + (x/2)^2) + x/2` numerically, for positive `x`. Using this expression directly fails for very large values of `x`. How can I rewrite it to obtain a more accurate evaluation?

Comment: There might be a numeric or large-value library for your language, but asking for such is off-topic (as you should know). Instead, what have you search for? What have you found? What have you tried? And what is the language you're programming in?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why off-topic? I am programming in Julia, but the question should apply to any language which follows floating point. I am not asking for a big float library solution. I am asking for a way of rewriting this for better accuracy.

Comment: If you want a language-agnostic solution then please add that tag. If you want a Julia-specific solution then please add that tag.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Done. I think the solution can be discussed at pseudo-code level

Comment: Newton-Raphson can be useful for square roots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For very large `x` you can factor out an `x/2`:

```
sqrt(1 + (x/2)^2) + x/2
 = (x/2) * sqrt( 1/(x/2)^2 + (x/2)^2/(x/2)^2) + x/2
 = (x/2) * sqrt( (2/x)^2 + 1 ) + x/2
```

For `x > 2/sqrt(eps)` the square root will actually evaluate to 1 and your whole expression will simplify to just `x`.
Assuming you need to cover the entire range `[0, infinity]`, I would suggest just branching at that point and return `x` in this case and your original formula, otherwise:

```
if x > 2/sqrt(eps)  // eps is the machine epsilon of your float type
    return x
else
    return sqrt(1 + (x/2)^2) + x/2
```

Comment: Maybe I can just use this expression for all `x`.

Comment: I should branch at `x = 1`?

Comment: I added a suggestion how to cover all floats (no need for division)

Comment: @BrettHale `(4/x)` could overflow for very small `x`, so at least one should factor out another `sqrt(4)`: `sqrt(x) * sqrt((1/x) + x/4) + (x/2)` -- but you'd still need to branch for 0 (and possibly for sub-normals) *and* you need to calculate two `sqrt` (instead of one) as well as one inverse.

Comment: @chtz - you're right. And that `(4/x)` would propagate `+Inf` into the calculation for say, a small sub-normal value - the question explicitly only deals with `(x > 0)`.

Answer (score 4):

Many programming languages offer a function `hypot(x,y)` that computes `sqrt (x*x + y*y)` while avoiding overflow and underflow in intermediate computation. Many implementations of `hypot` also compute the result more accurately than the naive expression. These advantages come at the expense of a moderate increase in run time.

With this function, the given expression can be written as `hypot (1.0, 0.5*x) + 0.5*x`. If your programming language of choice does not support `hypot` or an equivalent function, you may be able to adapt the implementation I provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58529704/780717).

Answer (score 3):

**Note** It's been pointed out that the Herbie generated expression may not be suitable in all contexts. In particular, metrics used to "improve" the expression by Herbie may generate expressions that perform worse for your particular scenario. So, take its output with a grain salt. I think you can still consult with Herbie to get an idea, but do *not* use it as a drop-in replacement.

Herbie (https://herbie.uwplse.org/) recommends the following replacement for your expression:

[image]

Or, in C:

```
double code(double x) {
    return ((double) (((double) sqrt(((double) (1.0 + ((double) pow((x / 2.0), 2.0)))))) + (x / 2.0)));
}
```

becomes:

```
double code(double x) {
    double VAR;
    if (((x / 2.0) <= -8569.643649604539)) {
        VAR = (1.0 / ((double) ((1.0 / ((double) pow(x, 3.0))) - ((double) (x + (1.0 / x))))));
    } else {
        double VAR_1;
        if (((x / 2.0) <= 7.229769585372425e-11)) {
            VAR_1 = ((double) ((x / 2.0) + ((double) sqrt(((double) (1.0 + ((double) pow((x / 2.0), 2.0))))))));
        } else {
            VAR_1 = ((double) ((x / 2.0) + ((double) (((double) ((1.0 / x) + ((double) (x * 0.5)))) - (1.0 / ((double) pow(x, 3.0)))))));
        }
        VAR = VAR_1;
    }
    return VAR;
}
```

It generates a detailed report on why it splits it into three regions. The output of Herbie can be rather hard to read, and it's been reported that it may not be better, but perhaps it can provide an alternative view.

Comment: The split at `7.23e-11` looks spurious -- and indeed trying an argument like `1e-9` using the last branch gives something near `-1e27`, while it should be a value close to 1. When providing a `x>=0` precondition, it gives a result which looks more plausible, though: [link (not sure if this is stable)](https://herbie.uwplse.org/demo/8953c6a594c9835cdc2e99e57ee53948dc86e0ef.bcfc386df7dce61b9961ec7b0a896641c066a0aa/graph.html).

Comment: @chtz Interesting, If you think this is a bug, I'm sure they'd appreciate a ticket: https://github.com/uwplse/herbie/issues

Comment: I've yet to see any case of herbie's output that's not either (a) unhelpful, or (b) plain wrong. Even something simple like `sqrt(1+x^2) - x` (which has numerical issues that are resolved by using `1 / (sqrt(1+x^2) + x)` for positive `x`) gives crazy output.

Comment: That is really unfortunate. Did you try reporting the issues you found to them? In my somewhat limited experience, they're quite responsive to bug reports, and recording the issues you saw would definitely help.

Comment: @alias: I'm not sure there's much constructive I could put into a bug report, that hasn't already been reported by others. For example, one of the problems I'm observing is this: https://github.com/uwplse/herbie/issues/261, which is essentially closed as a "won't fix". I may leave a comment on that issue.

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/uwplse/herbie/issues/333, too.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks. Your concerns are valid. I've edited the answer to point out the Herbie output needs to be separately validated.

Comment: It seems that's what really going on here is not really a bug: Herbie is working as designed, but the metrics that Herbie is using aren't necessarily a good match for what a typical user might want.

Answer (score 1):

**`hypot()`**

> The hypot functions compute the square root of the sum of the squares of x and y, without undue overflow or underflow. A range error may occur.

Code may then get a better result with `hypot(1,x/2) + x/2`;