# Why is Math.hypot so slow?

Tags: javascript, performance, distance, benchmarking, square-root

I am performing a *ton* of distance calculations in my code, to the point where `Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b)` is run hundreds of thousands of times.

I then recalled how there is a `Math.hypot` function that does exactly this. However, in all the testing I've done, it seems *significantly* slower than doing `Math.sqrt`. For example, if you run the following code:

```js
var i, tmp, x = 55, y = 66, end, ini = performance.now();

// Math.sqrt operation
i = 0;
ini = performance.now();
tmp = 0;
while(i++ < 2000000){
  tmp += Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)
}
end = performance.now();
console.log(tmp, "Math.sqrt operation: " + (end - ini) + " ms");

// Math.hypot

i = 0;
ini = performance.now();
tmp = 0;
while(i++ < 2000000){
  tmp += Math.hypot(x, y)
}
end = performance.now();

console.log(tmp, "Math.hypot: " + (end - ini) + " ms");
```

On my computer the `hypot` function is 5x slower. And I tried a [benchmarking site](https://jsben.ch/QKdhj) as well and there it was *25x* slower.

What is causing the `hypot` function to be so slow? Should it not be used at all for performance critical distance calculations, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, `Math.hypot` does [do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot#description) [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot#polyfill) than just `Math.sqrt`, but performance also seems to be browser dependent; that benchmark link under Firefox is almost a wash (`4606` vs `4493`) whereas in Chrome and Safari it's a complete rout (`4519` vs `164` and `9276` vs `294` respectively).

Comment: Do any of those implementations do anything special that would take more work, like not underflowing or overflowing `x*x` with x = `DBL_MIN` or `DBL_MAX`?  If you just get `0` or `+Inf` from `hypot(DBL_MIN or MAX, 0)`, then it's probably just doing the same thing as `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`. But if you get the original number back even in that case where the temporary would overflow, it must be doing something more than the straightforward "naive" implementation.

Comment: @msbit Gotcha, feel free to add that as an answer if you want. That makes sense. I didn't know `hypot` had all that extra functionality.

Comment: @RyanPeschel I'm happy to leave it at a comment ✌️

Comment: Closely [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764978/why-hypot-function-is-so-slow)